# SQL First capital letter - Function bad performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-function, capitalize

I have found the next function to capitalize the first letter of every word in a column:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 1

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END

    IF @PrevChar IN (' ')
    BEGIN
        IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
            SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
    END

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @OutputString

END

GO
```

If have have the next list of name:

```
ruth adams
sara black
john balley
```

I should get the next result

```
Ruth Adams
Sara Black
John Balley
```

But instead of that I'm getting this:

```
Uth Adams
Sara Black
John Balley
```

I lost the first letter of the first word. I have analyzed the function several times, but at this point I can understand this result set. Can you indicate me where the problem is, and if it is possible, how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify which dbms product you are using. (Since this is certainly not ANSI/ISO standard SQL.)

Comment: SQL Server 2012 , is this what you mean?

Comment: That's right! (You'll get better answer faster if you specify dbms, at least when asking about provider specific functionality.)

Answer (score 1):

You have this block of logic:

```
BEGIN
    IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
----------------------------^
        SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
END
```

You are intentionally removing `'S'`s.  I assume you just want:

```
BEGIN
    IF @PrevChar <> '''' 
        SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
END
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, but I think this part of the code is for British surnames, something like "johnson's" or something like that. Even whit the change that you propose, the final result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution. I did not know that the len function in sql does not take into account the last character if this is a white space, for that reason it was necessary to perform the RTRIM function in the column before use the Capitalize function

Answer (score 0):

This might be an alternative way of doing it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NameCap] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Index INT

SET @InputString = STUFF(@InputString, 1, 1, UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString, 1, 1)))
SET @Index = 2

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)

BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1) = ' '
        SET @InputString = STUFF(@InputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)))

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @InputString

END

GO
```